# Adding files from another computer to my SVN repository in Xcode 4

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4

I am trying to use the built in SVN in Xcode 4?
My main problem is how to add a new created class from other computer to my project.

Comment: What SVN client are you using? Smart SVN?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i tried the built in source control for Xcode 4, i tried adding classes then going to "add" feature then committing the change, but on the other device either the project see the class with red color or it doesn't see it at all.

Answer (score 0):

At the SVN control there should be an "adding files" option. Such as in Smart SVN for example, you can see the folder, where your project is, but near the recently added files appears "unversioned". You should right click on the file, and press "Add file to Smart SVN control" or sthg similar.

The method should be something similar at each SVN control system.

Comment: thanx a lot,i tried this but it doesn't give me the expected result:(

Comment: How about the file list/project structure in XCode? Does the version control letters (A, D, U) appear near the file names?